Mastering Foundry Basics
I'm interested in learning Foundry. What are the most effective resources and strategies you recommend for getting started with Foundry?

I recommend starting with the Cyfrin Foundry Fundamentals course.
https://updraft.cyfrin.io/courses/foundry
